# Can not mix get and filter together?

Tags: sqlalchemy

When I am trying to get next query:

```
answer = sess.query(User).filter(User.id==1).get(1)
```

I am getting error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Query.get() being called on a Query with existing criterion.`

The query:

```
answer = sess.query(User).get(1)
```

works fine.

Why the first one is not working?

My class definition:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    adr = relationship('Address', backref='uuu')
```

Comment: Answered the question, but why would you need to combine the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation of [`Query.get`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get):

> `get()` is only used to return a single mapped instance, not multiple instances or individual column constructs, and strictly on a single primary key value. The originating Query must be constructed in this way, i.e. against a single mapped entity, **with no additional filtering criterion**. Loading options via options() may be applied however, and will be used if the object is not yet locally present.